# Check params presence in Grape

Tags: ruby, rest, mongoid, ruby-grape

I'm playing with Grape gem and trying to build API, just to feed my curiosity. Now I want to implement feature that allows to use single route to get list of all objects or list of objects that specified in body of request. Also I'm using Mongoid as data mapper so I assume method should look like below:

```
params do
    optional :color, type: String
    optional :size,  type: Integer
end
get :catalog do
    if declared(params)
        Product.where declared(params)
    else
        Product.all
    end
end
```

But it doesn't work, response always returns complete list of objects presented in collection, no matter what data request body contains. Does this mean that `declared(params)` evaluates to `false`? But when I'm placing strings to `if` block it returns first string as `true` evaluation.

Can you explain me how it works? And can I implement that single-route feature?

*Thank you in advance.*

Comment: You are trying to execute kinda `where TRUE` query, which apparently returns everything. You do likely want to build query like (in pseudocode) `Product.where :color = declared(params)[:color] ...`.

Comment: Debug what does really `declared(params)` return, it should work *almost* as you expect it to, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method doesn't work cause by default Grape provides even `nil` values in `declared(params)` hash. So if `:color` provided but `:size` is not, hash looks like `{declared_params: {color: 'green', size: nil}}`, which is not acceptable for Mongoid. All magic is hidden in `include_missing` option provided by `declared`. So assignment that option to `false` like `Product.where declared(params, include_missing: false)` will cut all `nil` values and Mongoid starts to accept `declared` hash.